# Can you access NumPy core math library constants from python?

Tags: python, numpy

NumPy provides a [C API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html) with some useful constants like `NPY_LOG10E`.  I know I could just calculate them in python, but can I import those constants directly?

Just digging through the `numpy.FOO.` tab complete recommendations in IPython isn't getting me anywhere.

Comment: I don't think all of these constants are exposed at the Python level, no. There's only `pi`, `e` and `euler_gamma` available. [This is where these three constants are set](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/core/src/umath/umathmodule.c#L369-L374) - it's possible to add to this list and recompile NumPy if you want to have them!

Answer (score 0):

As `@ajcr` commented some constants are defined in [UMATH source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/core/src/umath/umathmodule.c#L369-L374).  That can be imported with:

```
In [193]: from numpy.core import umath as foo
In [194]: foo.pi
Out[194]: 3.141592653589793
In [195]: foo.e
Out[195]: 2.718281828459045
In [198]: foo.euler_gamma
Out[198]: 0.5772156649015329
```

Cython loads these (and more) in https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/math.pxd from `numpy/npy_math.h`

```
In [203]: np.math.e
Out[203]: 2.718281828459045
In [204]: np.math.pi
Out[204]: 3.141592653589793
```